# How is a Realm sync effected by unchanged data?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

If I call realm.create() and pass in a primary key for an entry that already exists, my understanding is that it does an update as opposed to an insert.

If I am using the realm server and one client calls a realm.create() on an existing entry and updates all the fields with the exact same data that was already in the row, will other clients see a need to sync that row, or since none of the data changed will they know to ignore it?

Is a sync needed flag generated on a row by diffing previous and current data, or by on some meta data based on when the entry was last edited regaurdless if the data changed?

I ask because I have a situation where one client could potentially call realm.create() on thousands of existing rows even though no data will have changed and I don't want my other clients to have to perform a huge sync as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm's sync is based off the actual database operations rather than the state. More specifically, the database maintains a transaction or operation log and the data sync is based off transmitting this data. For example, if you perform `realm.create('Object', {foo:bar, id: 0}, true)` which is an upsert operation for the `Object` with `id:0`, this will be written to the log and synchronized.

The result is that even if the upsert doesn't change any of the data, the operation must still be synced. The reasoning for this is that the sync uses operational transformation algorithms to automatically ensure that all changes across devices eventually become consistent. This works by ensuring eventually the server receives every operation.

As a result, you should be mindful of unnecessary operations if possible. Note the sync is highly optimized and by only syncing operations the data transfer is reduced compared to resending an entire object on each change.

Longer term we will be adding support for log compaction on the server. This will mean that clients will still always need to transmit their operations to the server, but the server could reduce operations needed to converge other clients (for example, collapsing multiple set operations down to the just the final set).